# Group by range of unix timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to group results from a table  per minute from a MongoDB collection.

I have a collection where I have more or less a document per second. With the following prototype:

```
{
    _id: ...
    type: "value",
    time: 1424421975,
    data: number
}
```

Now I want to create a second collection with the same prototype which is grouped first by type and then with time (per minute).

I already tried some things with the map reduce from MongoDB but I was not able to make this working.

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
    var firstTimestamp = db.collection.find({type: this.type}).sort({time: 1}).limit(1)[0].time;

    var keyValue = Math.floor((this.time - firstTimestamp) / 60) * 60 + firstTimestamp;

    emit(this.type + '_' + keyValue, this);
}

var reduceFunction1 = function(key, value) {
    return value;
};

db.loadServerScripts();
db.runCommand({
    mapreduce: "collection", 
    map: mapFunction1, 
    reduce: reduceFunction1, 
    out: "map_reduce_example",
    scope: {db: db}
});
```

Gives the error message:

```
    {
    "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Object db.collection has no method 'find' near 'collection.find({type:this.type'  (line 2)",
    "code" : 16722,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to get the first timestamp? Wouldn't rounding off the time be sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregation pipeline for this. The trick is to group by minutes computed using the [arithmetic operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/#arithmetic-aggregation-operators):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" :  { 
        "_id" : { 
            "type" : "$type", 
            "minute" : {
                "$divide" : [
                    { "$subtract" : ["$time", { "$mod" : ["$time", 60] }] },
                    60
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "data" : { "$sum" : "$data" }    // assuming you want to add up data for seconds
    } }
])
```

If you want to adjust for different boundaries between minutes, add an offset to `$time` in the `$subtract` expression. If you want to make your life easier (in this case), replace `time` by an actual date type and use [`$minute`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/minute/#minute-aggregation).

Comment: Thank you!

I've used:
`.result.forEach(function(doc) { db.collection_average.insert(doc); });` to store the results in a new collection.

Comment: For hourly data. (Timestamp in unix milliseconds): 
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$match" : {'Tstmp': { $gte : 1448287523000, $lt : 1448291123000 }}} ,
    { "$group" :  {
        "_id" : {
            "Type" : "$Type",
            "hour" :{"$divide" : [{ "$subtract" : [{"$divide" : ["$Tstmp", 1000]}, { "$mod" : [{"$divide" : ["$Tstmp", 1000]}, 3600] }] }, 3600 ]}
        },
        "data" : { "$sum" : "$data" }    
    } }
])